# copy all the lines after the last line with vi(m)

Tags: unix, copy, vi

How can I double all the lines of a file in vi(m) after the last line

example:

```
foo
bar
hello
world
```

result:

```
foo
bar
hello
world
foo
bar
hello
world
```

I've tried the copy/paste commands without result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following in escape mode:

```
1G
yG
G
p
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command should do the trick

```
:%s/\(.*\)/\1\1/
```

Comment: No it doesn't. It duplicates each line, not the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
1GyGP
```

Goes to the first char on the first line, yanks the whole file and inserts it above.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
gg

:s/\_.*/&&
```